# Visual Studio style curly brackets auto completion in emacs

Tags: emacs, code-completion, brackets

I'm new to using emacs as I've been using Visual Studio before.
Is there a way to have the same kind of autocompletion for curly brackets in emacs ?

What I mean is, in Visual Studio if type this ("|" being the cursor) :

```
int foo()
{|
```

I get this :

```
int foo()
{
    |
}
```

I tried using electric-pair-mode but it just closes the curly bracket.
I hope I've been clear, english is not my native language.

EDIT : 
@Rupert Swarbrick the `electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs` doesn't seem to be set to true in my emacs. When I have `electric-pair-mode` enabled and that I press `return` after the bracket I get this :

```
int foo()
{
|}
```

The cursor is on the same line as the closing bracket and I have to manually go to the line above to write the code which is a bit annoying.
Where can I modify `electric-pair-mode` to check if it's set to true ? I haven't found it.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @Rupert Swarbrick for his help, I'm using `autopair.el` for now since I'm using emacs 24.3, it does what I wanted. For people using emacs 24.4 or higher `electric-pair-mode` has been upgraded and you can use what Rupert said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the guts of `electric-pair-mode`, it doesn't appear that you can do so by customising any variables, but all is not lost! If `electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs` is true (the default) then you'll find that typing `{` then the return key should give you the

```
{
    <- cursor here
}
```

that you want.

To avoid having to type the extra newline, we want to pretend that the user typed it immediately after typing the opening `{`. To do so, we can write the function below. This checks that `electric-pair-mode` is enabled, that we are expecting to open new lines between pairs (that `if` block is copied from the logic in `elec-pair.el`), that the user just typed a `{` and that we're sitting in a `{}` pair (the closing `}` will have been added by electric pair mode already. If these things are all true, it calls the `newline` function. The second argument specifies that it should behave as if the user actually typed the newline (rather than just inserting `\n` and stopping). At that point, the normal `electric-pair-mode` code runs and reindents everything as we want.

Finally, we need to make sure that this runs at the right time. One way to do so is to add it as "advice" to `electric-pair-post-self-insert-function`. That way, it will run at the right time whenever electric pair mode is enabled.

Stick the following elisp code in your `.emacs` and try it out:

```
(defun electric-pair-brace-fixup ()
  (when (and electric-pair-mode
             (if (functionp electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs)
                 (funcall electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs)
               electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs)
             (eq last-command-event ?\{)
             (= ?\{ (char-before)) (= ?\} (char-after)))
    (newline nil t)))

(advice-add 'electric-pair-post-self-insert-function :after
            #'electric-pair-brace-fixup)
```

Comment: My `electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs` seems not to be set to true but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Ah, it seems that the default value changed in Emacs 24.4: maybe you're using something older? Anyway, type `M-x customize-variable electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs` (there's tab-completion to avoid typing) to change its value.

Comment: Or alternatively you could add `(setq electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs t)` to the Lisp code above (type `C-x C-e` after the closing parenthesis to evaluate it)

Comment: I'm using emacs 24.3 and it's the latest version on Trisquel's repository. I've read that `electric-pair-mode` has been enhanced in 24.4 so I guess I have to update my emacs. I'm trying to build it and I'll see if your solution works. Thank you.

Comment: For a quick hack, just grab `elec-pair.el` from the later Emacs, open it, and try `eval-buffer`. If it works, you can either update your Emacs (knowing it's worth doing) or just keep using a locally modified `elec-pair.el` until your distribution updates its Emacs package.

Comment: Ok, when I enabled `electric-pair-mode` after evaluating the new `elec-pair.el` I got `progn: Symbol's function definition is void: electric--sort-post-self-insertion-hook` and when I press `return` after a bracket I get `and: Wrong number of arguments: <, 3`